# How to add legend in a subplot with multiple data in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning

I have a set of data and I want to add a legend to each subplot. I checked the documentation but still don't know how to do it. Could someone give me a clue? Thank you.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))
x1 = np.array([1, 0.01, 0.0001])
y1_1 = np.array([Train_s_l, Train_s_l001, Train_s_l00001])
y1_2 = np.array([Test_s_l, Test_s_l001, Test_s_l00001])
x2 = np.array([0.1, 1, 10])
y2_1 = np.array([Train_s_r01, Train_s_r, Train_s_r10])
y2_2 = np.array([Test_s_r01, Test_s_r, Test_s_r10])
axes[0].plot(x1, y1_1, x1, y1_2)
axes[0].set_title("Alpha for Lasso Regression")
axes[1].plot(x2, y2_1, x2, y2_2)
axes[1].axis('tight')
axes[1].set_title("Alpha for Ridge Regression")
```

[image]

Comment: add `label` option to `.plot` commands, then do `axes[0].legend()` and `axes[1].legend()`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But I still cannot tag blue and orange lines with different names.
axes[0].plot(x1, y1_1, x1, y1_2, label='Training Score')
How could I fix it?